# Export figures from powerpoint with latin modern font

Tags: fonts, powerpoint

so I want to create figures in powerpoint to integrate them in a latex document. I have installed latin modern fonts because they look similar than the latex font. I export the Figure in svg format and then convert it to eps. When i load them in latex, the fonts have changed. What can i do?

Thank you.

Edit:
By "they have changed" I mean they are not latin modern fonts anymore, but some other font (i think Calibri).

What I mean by integrate:

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{image1.eps}
   \caption{Image}
   \label{fig:im1}
\end{figure}
```

Powerpoint does not offer .pdf when you choose save as image. So I chose this way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with they have changed? Please explain better ...

Comment: Integrate how exactly? Please provide a minimal document explaining what you're doing. Is there any particular reason you're using eps? You can't export as pdf, for example?

Comment: You can actually just "save" the PPT as PDF. Then you can easily insert pages from this PDF to your document.

Comment: Saving the image to svg actually works really well, the quality of the figure is really good. the only problem is the change of the font.